# Angular [selected] property only runs on init

Tags: angular, html-select

I use a select with some options which will be set by a ngFor loop. Each option has  the `[selected]` property and should print the index to console when its selected. The problem is the function will be executed when the page is refreshes/loaded and not when the value from the dropdown is clicked.

This is a minimal example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-select-rppf99

I'm using Anuglar 5+ at the moment

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-select-udzk1y?file=app/app.component.html you would want to listen to changes in the dropdown, not `selected`.

Comment: is it also possible to pass the index of the selected option item?

Comment: @WeSt I guess you could use `ngValue`, pass an object, if you want both the index and the value: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-select-vqfu8q?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: @AJT_82 we get closer to the goal. It would be easier for the rest of my project if I just could pass the index to the executing function without changing the ngValue to a object or change in any way

Comment: well then you just set the index as the value: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-select-vm3apb?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: You can also use (change)="AddTarget($event)"
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-select-udzk1y

Comment: @AJT_82 I mean to keep `[value]="target.id"``(without changing) and passing the index of the selected option to the executing function

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you are trying to achieve :D But this should do what you want: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-select-2hgefb?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: @AJT_82 that looks like what he wants! Nice job

Comment: @AJT_82 perfect, thats what I need :) post it as answer and I accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selected` would be used, when you want to have an initial option selected in the dropdown. What you want, is to listen to changes in the dropdown. If you want to pass the index to the function, but keep the id as `value` then you can use vanilla JS and `$event` to get the selected index :)

```html
<select (change)="AddTarget($event.target.selectedIndex)">
  <option *ngFor="let target of availableTargets; let i = index" [value]="target.id" >
    {{target.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

**DEMO: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-select-2hgefb?file=app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on @AJT_82's answer in the comment section. If you want to specifically find the index you have to change the `[value]` being passed in i.e. `i` for the index. Otherwise you can change it to `target.id` for instance if you would like to pass the `id` into the function.

Here is the edited example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-select-j5u27t?file=app/app.component.html

Let me know if you need anything further explained.